# error al obetener data de un web service con Retrofit

Tags: android, webservice, retrofit

Tengo una app terminada que en algunas ocasiones le crashea a mis usuarios (a mi no me lo hace)... google me manda este stack trace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentPrincipal. 
   realizarCambioPrecio(FragmentPrincipal.java:181)  
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentPrincipal.
   access$200(FragmentPrincipal.java:42)
at com.mal.saul.preciosbitcoinmexico.Fragment.FragmentPrincipal$2.
   onResponse(FragmentPrincipal.java:160)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.
   run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5637)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method:0)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller. 
   run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

A lo que entiendo estoy teniendo el error en el metodo onResponse de Retroft, aqui se los adjunto junto con el onFailure:

```
@Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ValoresBtcPrecioResponse> call, 
        Response<ValoresBtcPrecioResponse> response) {                
            ValoresBtcPrecioResponse valoresBtcPrecioResponse = 
            response.body();
            if(valoresBtcPrecioResponse != null){
                valoresBtcPrecios = 
                valoresBtcPrecioResponse.getValoresBtcPrecio();
                mostrarValoresBtcPrecio();  //muestra a traves de Textviews 
                //los valores contenids en valoresBtcPrecios (es global)                                                        
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Bitso No Está Disponible Por 
            el Momento", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
@Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ValoresBtcPrecioResponse> call, Throwable          
        t) {                     
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sin Conexión a Internet", 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Como ya mencioné el error no me acurre a mi, son los reportes que mandan los usuarios, habia puesto el if(valoresBtcPrecioResponse != null) precisamente para evita el null pointer, alguna idea de como solucionarlo?

Comment: Trata de basar tu revisión en el LogCat eso evitará perder tiempo en tratar de buscar un problema, que es la linea 181 de FragmentPrincipal.java.

Comment: no puedo hacer eso porque el error no me ocurre a mi, como veo el stack trace en el logcat de un error que no es mio?

Comment: a que te refieres con un error que no es tuyo!

Comment: subi la app a la play store de google, el crasheo le ha sucedido a algunos usuarios, a mi no, por lo tanto no puedo ver su comportamiento en el logcat

Comment: Si tienes la clase FragmentPrincipal.java podrías agregarla?